# Is there any sense of applying cross validation to quasibinomial variable?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, econometrics, quasi-likelihood

We can apply without any doubts cross validation for linear models as well as for binary models.

For linear models for example we can output RMSE and MAE and Accuracy for binary models.

But I have some queries about performing cross validation for quasibinomial variables. Lets consider :

```
set.seed(42)
y <- 1 / (1 + exp(-rnorm(125)))
x <- rexp(125)
model <- train(y ~ .,
  data = cbind(y, x), method = "glm",
  family = quasibinomial(),
  trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)
)
model

    No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 100, 100, 98, 101, 101 
Resampling results:

  RMSE       Rsquared   MAE      
  0.2117914  0.0330701  0.1758352
```

My question is : we can perform it, but is there any theoretical sense of applying it ? I mean is the RMSE and MAE interpretable in quasibinomial case? Can we grain some relevant information from this ? Or maybe are there any other metrics which are better for quasibinomial cross-validation ?

Comment: I can see no reason that models estimated with quasi-likelihood can not be evaluated with cross-validation. You could use some proper scoring rule such as the Brier score?

Comment: Brier score is nothing else than MSE between predictions and actual.

Comment: I agree with @kjetil-b-halvorsen - I see no obvious reason not to. Quasi models still predict correct means, which is all you care about for CV.